# TextView1 by click to jump to TextView2 in the ScrollView

Tags: android, text, scroll, textview

I made "TextView1" clickable in the ScrollView and I need to make the screen go much lower in the text to "TextView2" text.

Comment: Did I understand you? Do you mean, you want to scroll to textview2 on textview1 click action? What does it mean: 'make the screen go much lower'? Waiting for answer.

Comment: Exactly. You understood well. It is like on the top you have all song titles and below you have titles with all the lyrics. And when i click on one song name at the begining i want the screen to go down to the title of the song i clicked.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Here you dont just write what you want. You must also tell us what efforts you have put to solve your problem and what didnt work. Possibly also add a sample code. Read faq for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is my layout:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:onClick="doClick"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1500dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="sdfasiufhadifhissipaghuopghshgiahipuhguiashguipahguiphiughsdupaghapsghasuipghasughpgh" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**And this is my code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ScrollView scrollView;
private TextView textViewAim;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        scrollView =  (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_scrollview);
        textViewAim = (TextView)   findViewById(R.id.textViewText);
    }

    public void doClick(View view){
        if (view.getId() == R.id.textViewTitle) {
            int[] location = new int[2];
            textViewAim.getLocationOnScreen(location);
            scrollView.scrollTo(location[0], location[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

**enjoy!**

Comment: Thank you for your help guys. I did exactly as you wrote and it really worked well. I tried with OnClickListener but after hours of trying i quitted being stubborn and asked here. This code looks like it is not much but for me it is a life savior. I will read faq now and be arround coz i'm sure there are many useful things around here. Thanks once more!!